# How to make the Notification Center menu icon glow, (like Twitter does) when notifications are present?

Tags: macos, menu-bar, notifications

Notification Center is pretty great, however, it's very annoying that I have to click the menubar icon or make a gesture to actually open the notification pane.

How to make the Notification Center menu icon glow, (like Twitter does) when notifications are present, or something similar?

Comment: Umm...isn't that what the popup/banner notification is for?

Comment: In earlier developer builds of Mountain Lion, the notification center icon used to glow when there would be "unread" notifications. This is worth looking into, as there might be a hidden setting to turn it on.

Comment: daviesgeek the problem comes when your eyes are out of screen and the 3 second banner disappear

Comment: bogdansrc yep that will be perfect

Comment: @EnforcerW why not change the notification type to from 'banner' to 'alert'?

Comment: @bogdansrc As you know, Developer Previews include features as well as bugs that often change and get lost before final release. This seems to be one of those cases.

Comment: oh, that's too bad

Answer (score -5):

The only solution is jailbreak - which is not advised... In iOS 7 you don't get it either (I'm running the beta) and there is no hidden setting.

Comment: The question is about Mountain Lion, not iOS...

Comment: Oops haha - not sure then - there may be a hack out there on the internet